# How to join 2 cell in 1 cell in header?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Above is my dataframe, and I wish to get this out put on header

[image]

Anyone have idea on this?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). It would be much easier for us to provide an answer, if there was code to produce the input data instead of having to reproduce data from an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = ['201701', '', '201705', '', '201707']
b = ['PHI', 'Actual', 'Actual', 'PHI', 'Actual']
data = [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8, np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['ClassCold'], columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a,b]))
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['', '201701', '201705', '201707'], ['Actual', 'PHI']],
           labels=[[1, 0, 2, 0, 3], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

print (df)
          201701        201705     201707
             PHI Actual Actual PHI Actual
ClassCold    NaN    NaN    NaN   8    NaN
```

Get first level of `MultiIndex` by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), convert to `Series` by [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) empty strings (or space) to `NaN` and forward fill `NaN`s by [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html).

Last create new `MultiIndex` [`from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
a = df.columns.get_level_values(0).to_series().replace('',np.nan).ffill()
df.columns = df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a, df.columns.get_level_values(1)])
print (df)
          201701        201705     201707
             PHI Actual Actual PHI Actual
ClassCold    NaN    NaN    NaN   8    NaN

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['201701', '201705', '201707'], ['Actual', 'PHI']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```